# cpu intense js animation, can it be the setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, setinterval

I'm making a simple background animation: basically I'd like to have 3 shapes smoothly bouncing around the screen. my reference is the well-known "dvd screensaver effect".

Starting from [this tuorial](https://youtu.be/wMIARRCox9k) I built my version with 3 pngs bouncing around and this is the result.

The problem is that when I run it I've noticed that my laptop fans immediately starts to run and sometimes it jerks, since I wanted to add this effect to a website I'm making (with some other content already), I'm afraid the animation would be even more laggy.

I wanted to ask you if you recommend any way, to make this animation run smoother and less cpu intense. I was wondering if the problem could be se function setInterval and if there could be some other function lighter for the cpu to run.

I've tried also to reduce the png size or use svg but I guess that the blur effect on the svg made the animation even more heavy

Thank you!

```js
const section = document.querySelector(".bg-animation");
  const logo = document.querySelector(".shape-bg-1");
  const logo2 = document.querySelector(".shape-bg-2");
  const logo3 = document.querySelector(".shape-bg-3");

  const FPS = 60;

  var widthLimite = $('.bg-animation').outerWidth();
  var heightLimite = $('.bg-animation').outerHeight();

  section.style.height = heightLimite;
  section.style.width = widthLimite;

  // Logo moving velocity Variables
  let xPosition = 10;
  let yPosition = 10;

  let x2Position = 20;
  let y2Position = 30;

  let x3Position = 70;
  let y3Position = 20;

  $(".shape-bg-1").css('opacity',1);
  $(".shape-bg-2").css('opacity',1);
  $(".shape-bg-3").css('opacity',1);


  //velocità
  let xSpeed = 0.8;
  let ySpeed = 0.8;

  let x2Speed = 0.9;
  let y2Speed = 0.6;

  let x3Speed = 0.7;
  let y3Speed = 0.9;

  function update() {
    logo.style.left = xPosition + "px";
    logo.style.top = yPosition + "px";

    logo2.style.left = x2Position + "px";
    logo2.style.top = y2Position + "px";

    logo3.style.left = x3Position + "px";
    logo3.style.top = y3Position + "px";
  }

  setInterval(() => {
    if (xPosition + logo.clientWidth >= widthLimite || xPosition <= 0) {
      xSpeed = -xSpeed;
    }
    if (yPosition + logo.clientHeight >= heightLimite || yPosition <= 0) {
      ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    }
    //shape2
    if (x2Position + logo2.clientWidth >= widthLimite || x2Position <= 0) {
      x2Speed = -x2Speed;
    }
    if (y2Position + logo2.clientHeight >= heightLimite || y2Position <= 0) {
      y2Speed = -y2Speed;
    }
    //shape3
    if (x3Position + logo3.clientWidth >= widthLimite || x3Position <= 0) {
      x3Speed = -x3Speed;
    }
    if (y3Position + logo3.clientHeight >= heightLimite || y3Position <= 0) {
      y3Speed = -y3Speed;
    }

    xPosition += xSpeed;
    yPosition += ySpeed;

    x2Position += x2Speed;
    y2Position += y2Speed;

    x3Position += x3Speed;
    y3Position += y3Speed;

    update();
  }, 1000 / FPS);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.title {
  font-family: 'arial','helvetica',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.home-bg-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.bg-animation {
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
}
.shape-bg-1,
.shape-bg-2, 
.shape-bg-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 80vw;
  opacity: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="home-bg-container">
      <div class="bg-animation">
        <img class="shape-bg-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/HgpGbh4/shape1-min.png" alt="">
        <img class="shape-bg-2" src="https://i.ibb.co/Pm6bmHj/shape2-min.png" alt="">
        <img class="shape-bg-3" src="https://i.ibb.co/NCrH4GJ/shape3-min.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  <p class="title">SOME TEXT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The animation is quite CPU intense but the code is fine and I don't see any way to optimize it (at least not regarding the CPU load)

Comment: Actually, it was my guess that the animation was cpu intense (based on laggy effect/ fans start running), is there a way to check what is slowing down the browser?

Comment: You can check the CPU load by app in the task manager, and/or reduce the FPS; you can also try other blend modes, my guess is those are the primary reason